Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown by fetching large data in ASP.NET ajax webmethod
When I fetch data from Ajax to web method and show in datatable in ASP.NET using C#, at that time it showing a System.OutOfMemoryException error.
Here is my Ajax code:
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {                
    var dataToSend = {
        stockType: document.getElementById("<%=cmb_stocktype.ClientID%>").value,
        metalType: document.getElementById("<%=cmb_metaltype.ClientID%>").value,
        filterType: document.getElementById("<%=cmb_filtertype.ClientID%>").value,
        fromFilter: document.getElementById("<%=txt_fromfilter.ClientID%>").value == "" ? 0 : document.getElementById("<%=txt_fromfilter.ClientID%>").value,                
        toFilter: document.getElementById("<%=txt_tofilter.ClientID%>").value == "" ? 0 : document.getElementById("<%=txt_tofilter.ClientID%>").value
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FillGridMethod.asmx/StockList",
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {                    
            var datatableVariable = $('#gv_Datatable').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',              
                "bDestroy": true,
                "paging": true,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "info": true,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "responsive": true,
                data: data,
                columns: [                                      
                    { 'data': 'Product' },
                    { 'data': 'StockTagNo' },
                    { 'data': 'ItemPcs' },
                    { 'data': 'Carat' },
                    { 'data': 'GrossWeight' },
                    { 'data': 'Fine' },
                    { 'data': 'MRP' },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) { return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-success' onclick=DeleteCustomer('" + row.Id + "');>View</>"; }
                    },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, row) { return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>"; }
                    }],                 
            });                                                
        }
    });
});

Here is my web method code in the .asmx page:
[WebMethod(enableSession: true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void StockList(int stockType, string metalType, int filterType, decimal fromFilter = 0, decimal toFilter = 0)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["BranchId"].ToString() == null)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Index.aspx");
        return;
    }

    var stock = new List<StockModel>();
    string constr = cn.ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {                
        qryFillGrid = " Select * from tbl_StockRunning " + System.Environment.NewLine;

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qryFillGrid, con))
        {
            command.CommandTimeout = 120; // Timeout in seconds                                            
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    byte[] image = null;

                    if (dr[17].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        image = (byte[])dr[17];
                    }

                    var stockModel = new StockModel
                    {
                        StockId = Convert.ToInt32(service.IfNullThen(dr[0], 0)),
                        Product = dr[1].ToString(),
                        StockTagNo = dr[2].ToString(),
                        ItemPcs = Convert.ToInt32(service.IfNullThen(dr[3], 0)),
                        Carat = dr[4].ToString(),
                        GrossWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[5], 0)),
                        Fine = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[6], 0)),
                        MRP = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[7], 0)),
                        NetWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[8], 0)),
                        HUID = dr[9].ToString(),
                        labourchrg = Convert.ToDecimal(service.IfNullThen(dr[10], 0)),

                        labourunit = dr[11].ToString(),
                        OtherCharge = dr[12].ToString(),
                        HMCharge = Convert.ToInt32(service.IfNullThen(dr[13], 0)),
                        Size = dr[14].ToString(),
                        BoxNo = dr[15].ToString(),
                        Remarks = dr[16].ToString(),

                        DesignImage = image,
                        Party = dr[18].ToString()
                    };

                    stock.Add(stockModel);
                }
            }
        }                
    }

    // when the amount of data return is huge
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    // we need to do this.
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    var result = serializer.Serialize(stock);

    Context.Response.Write(result);
}

On this line of code:
var result = serializer.Serialize(stock);

I'm getting that error mentioned.
